# Command Prompt auto confirm message pop up window

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm running a batch file that runs a command line, mid way in the command, there is a message pop up where once has to press "OK" in order to continue processing the command. Is there something I can add that would auto confirm this pop up?

Comment: What is the specific command being called?

Comment: Does hitting Enter press the OK button? Using `echo.` (no space) is equivalent to hitting Enter for some purposes. Try `echo. | myfile.bat`

Comment: call myfile.bat from another bat file?

Comment: Perhaps, but just try typing that at the command line first to see if it works!

Comment: didnt work I went to cmd and typed in 'echo. | myfile.bat' however popup still apeears

Comment: what command asks for a visual popup? is it a native program?

Comment: yes, I have no control over it

Comment: I've used [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) in the past to get past such issues.

Comment: If the popup window has focus when it appears, you could employ a `Wscript.Shell` COM object's `SendKeys()` method using either VBScript or JScript, or a PowerShell command.  I think `powershell "(new-object -COM Wscript.Shell).SendKeys('~')"` would send an Enter keypress to the active window, whatever that happens to be.  If that doesn't work, you could stick an `AppActivate('titlebar text')` in there somewhere.  Just out of curiosity, is the command you're running `psexec`?  If so, there's a registry entry you can add to programmatically accept the EULA and bypass the need to hit OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [`sendKeys.bat`](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat).It accepts two arguments - window title where keys will be sent and a string with a keys which will be "pressed" (microsoft reference with of the [SendKeys function](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx)) .Here's example how it can be used to close `Yes/No` and `Ok` pop-ups:

```
C:\>start "" /min powershell [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("""System.Windows.Forms""");[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::show("""HelloWorld""", """My PopUp Message Box""",4)
C:\>call sendkeys.bat "My PopUp Message" "Y"
```

or

```
C:\>start "" /min powershell [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("""System.Windows.Forms""");[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::show("""HelloWorld""", """My PopUp Message Box""")
C:\>call sendkeys.bat "My PopUp Message" "{ENTER}"
```

**EDIT** .not tested:

```
@echo off

:repeat
w32tm /stripchart /computer:localhost /period:1 /dataonly /samples:10  >nul 2>&1
call sendkeys.bat "Some Title" "Y" || (
    goto :repeat
)&&(
    goto :end
)
:end
```

this will try to send keys on every 10 seconds.

Comment: Great, but how you setup the batch file to catch the pop-up? The popup appears midway processing. SHould I set a timer for the sendkeys?

Comment: @EM90210 - check my edit.It will try to send keys on every 10 seconds and will stop on success.I suppose you can tune this to apply better on your needs.